# Android KitKat (4.4) video autoplay does not work anymore in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

on previous versions of Android, we were be able to start a video by calling play() method on video js element or by simulating a click event on it (only for some specifics devices such as nexus on which the video does not start at all), now it's working anymore... i understand that we should not allow this for android chrome version or android web navigator, but why also inside webview ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try calling `WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)` for your WebView.

(see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean) )

Comment: I also have Android 4.4.3 and it doesn't work on that either, even after using `WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)`

Comment: Cordova-People: Add this right below `super.init();`: `super.appView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);` (tested on cordova 3.5 with remote video).

Comment: I downvoted because I thought the answer didn't seem to address the poster's issue, and because I was having the issue of the suggestion not working, BUT i discovered that the solution wasn't working because I had accidentally disabled hardware acceleration (by setting the layout something to null).  So, apologies for the down vote, and I can confirm it still works in 4.4, as long as hardware acceleration is on.

Comment: @QuinxyvonBesiex I've tested it myself and not working, after enabling  hardwareacceleration for the hole app on manifestfile, the webView still doesn't have hardware acceleration. so I would like to know how exactly you did it.  for me <application          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
... /> didn't work. did you face something similar?