# HTMLVideoElement won't autoplay on a Cordova Android App

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

I'm working on a Cordova app, which has a QR code reader. It works by using WebRTC API. I'm trying to get it to autoplay without require user interaction with the page. But it only works sometimes, most of the time it won't autoplay and shows ugly grey square with a play button.

Here's what was done so far.

The video element is **muted**, set to **autoplay** and **play inline**:

```
const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
videoElement.style.width = `${width}px`;
videoElement.muted = true;
videoElement.playsInline = true;
videoElement.autoplay = true;
return videoElement;
```

Once the video started, the **play()** method is executed after 1 second:

```
let Element = $('video')[0];
Element.autoplay = true;

setTimeout(() => { Element.play() }, 1000);
```

The Cordova WebView setting which requires user interaction is set to **false**.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    
    // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
    
    WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // <-- This is the important part
}
```

Nevertheless, the camera stream still doesn't play automatically once it's created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Flowplayer to automatically play in Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706111/how-to-get-flowplayer-to-automatically-play-in-android-webview)

Comment: @Eric this does not work all the time. I still face the problem I've described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons and tons attempts, googling and trying different JS camera libraries, I can simply tell that **it's not possible to consistently autoplay videos in a Cordova app**.

However, there is still solution. But it's completely different approach.

**You have to simulate a screen tap.** Luckily, it's very easy.

1. Go to your platforms/android/app/src/main/java/***your package***/MainActivity.java.
2. Add the following imports:

```
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.view.InputDevice;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
```

3. In the **onCreate()** handler add the following:

```
    webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "AndroidApp");
```

4. Add the following class as **a nested class** to the MainActivity class:

```
    class JSInterface
    {       
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void SimulateScreenTap()
        {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    long delta = 100;
                    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    float x = webView.getLeft() + (webView.getWidth() / 2);
                    float y = webView.getTop() + (webView.getHeight() / 2);
    
                    MotionEvent tapDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
                    tapDownEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);
    
                    MotionEvent tapUpEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta + 2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
                    tapUpEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);
    
                    webView.dispatchTouchEvent(tapDownEvent);
                    webView.dispatchTouchEvent(tapUpEvent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

5. Now when you need to start your video, simply call `AndroidApp.SimulateScreenTap()`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is a very big trap for developers.

Setting `muted` property of an HTMLVideoElement **will not count** as muted video for Android WebView.

**This does not work**:

```
videoElement.muted = true;
```

You have to add the `muted=true` attribute.

**This is the proper way**:

```
videoElement.setAttribute('muted', true);
```