# HTML5 Audio not working on Crosswalk Cordova or standard Cordova based WebView on Android 4.4

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, webview, html5-audio

I am trying to use the HTML Audio API to play a mp3 file from a remote HTTP source. Its flat out not working on either Android's default WebView based Cordova instance or using a Crosswalk Cordova blink based instance. The device is registering it as playing but no actual sound is emitted.

```
var audio = new Audio();


function playSong(url) {

    audio.src = url;
    audio.play();
}
```

The code above is a snippet with all the non-audio related stuff stripped out, i have the internet permission set added and the app works as hoped on the desktop (using Chrome 35).

Is it the case that i am missing a permission for playback or does there need to be a physical audio tag present on the page for it to work?

Comment: I have been having the same problem, 2 years later. Did you ever solve the issue? It only happens in KitKat, any newer OS works fine.

Comment: Went native, never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you ended up going Native, but I'll answer with what solved my problem. I was trying to make an HTML5 game with music that ran on Android 4.4, but it never worked. I have tried many things, and have been having this problem for months.

First off, Crosswalk's minimum [Android version is 4.0](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Which-platforms-does-Crosswalk-support) right now.

My issue was that I wasn't actually using Crosswalk. I think I was using it at some point, then switched computers and the plugin dependency wasn't saved to my config.xml. Anyways, something got mixed up, and it wasn't being included in my build. By default, crosswalk [builds an arm and x86 .apk files](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/build_an_application.html#build-application), I was only getting one. My apk also was only about `20.3MB`, after fixing this it jumped to `~42MB` (I think, somewhere around there).

After properly including XWalk, HTML5 audio worked and my game ran EXTREMELY more smoothly on Android 4.4. This is due to improved rendering tech on the new chromium browser.

### The Fix

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
#delete mentions of 'xwalk' from config.xml
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --save #ensure plugin gets saved to config.xml
```

Build again. If still not working (no arm and x86 apks, apks still small), delete old apk's in build/output dir, and build again

Answer (score -1):

It should be an auto play issue of Chrome WebView, see here
[Android KitKat (4.4) video autoplay does not work anymore in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673533/android-kitkat-4-4-video-autoplay-does-not-work-anymore-in-webview)

But for Crosswalk, the auto play has already been enabled by default, just double checked your sample with the latest Crosswalk binary, it works fine.
https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/canary/8.36.165.0/arm/crosswalk-cordova-8.36.165.0-arm.zip

Comment: I have tested with both the stable, beta and canary (the version linked) binaries of crosswalk and am seeing the same results. Its unusual because the play audio event is triggered and after the expected duration of the audio track passes the stop event is triggered (as is expected), ive modified my example so controls are set to false and autoplay is also set to false  and will report back with the results, failing this ill try using load and adding a callback to play as soon as the buffer fills to a playable amount and do the same.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, none of the above worked at all (it played once or twice but 90+ percent of the time no sound was emitted even though it would appear to be playing). Does ANYONE have ANY insight into this problem? The fact that HTML5 audio / video is such a mess on a platform released by one of the biggest browser vendors in the world is truly shocking...

Comment: Not quite understand your comments, could you provide more specific code sample? And what's the platform you used? I tested it on Nexus 5. If your failed case is still a simple play, it may be related with the platform. As Chrome uses the system media player on Android.

Comment: The example given up top is pretty clear as far as i can tell, the platform, rendering engine and code in question are all specified above, i will however modify the question to include my new efforts.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to manually add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml?