# html5 javascript autoplay not working on android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

I have a problem with video autostart in android browser(or in boat browser). It was worked and is working on android <4.2.2 version perfectly. But on android versions higher than 4.2.2 it can't get video to autostart, instead waiting for mouse click to play.
Below is shown the basic part of my code.

```js
<script>
var vid=document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
vid.addEventListener("loadstart", showVideo, false);

function showVideo() {
  vid.play();
}
</script>
```

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" src="videos/video1.mp4" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" autobuffer controls />
```

How to autostart mp4 video on android browser when android version >=4.4 ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)

WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)

Comment: How I know WebView not acting in browser. I want to autoplay my video into a browser.

Comment: Also I have added the WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) // in my javascript code but it did not help.

Comment: Can you adjust my code above please ?

Comment: I saw that as the answer on this exact same question here on SO.  It was marked as answer and had 11 upvotes.  Then as I read more, some say auto play doesn't work with Android at all anymore, which I find hard to believe.

Comment: Check the answer on this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673533/android-kitkat-4-4-video-autoplay-does-not-work-anymore-in-webview

And this is one of the comments on the answer

"I downvoted because I thought the answer didn't seem to address the poster's issue, and because I was having the issue of the suggestion not working, BUT i discovered that the solution wasn't working because I had accidentally disabled hardware acceleration (by setting the layout something to null). So, apologies for the down vote, and I can confirm it still works in 4.4"

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response dear David. I have saw that too, but unfortunately all answers related to WebView, but what if we want to autostart a mp4 video into a built-in browser?.
So I have not found an answer too.

Comment: I saw stackoverflow.com/questions/20673533, but it is also relating to WebView api, but my question to autostart a mp4 video not in WebView api, but into a built-in (or for instance in boat) browser.

Comment: Hi Harutyun, it seems that video auto play is indeed disabled on Android browsers now and wasn't before, too save users bandwidth if they want to visit a page and not have a video played without their own interaction (ex. a click).  That seems to be the reason.

Comment: OK, but anyway how can I force to autoplay?
Is there a variant to force autoplay?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not allow autoplay in mobile web, you have to allow autoplay when constructing the WebView in your native code, or route from a user event to the invocation of the `player.play()`

iOS can only play fullscreen in mobile web, if you want inline video it has to be in-app